# URL string does not return in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter

I try to query a series of rows in my MySQL database but whenever the value is a URL it does not display.

```
([Handle] => air-gap-parts 
 [productID] => 0000000018 
 [active] => 1 
 [tag] => 0 
 [ImageSrc] =>)
```

ImageSrc should yield a URL to a picture but every time it returns nothing. I'm using CodeIgniter and I am wondering if it has something to do with my .htaccess file?

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 

<Files "index.php">
  AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

CodeIgniter Model Query:

```
function get_product_pics($handle)<br />
{
  $this->db->where('handle', $handle);
  $query = $this->db->get('products_test_db');
  return $query->result();
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think the where of your query is wrong

Comment: Right you were, but after I changed the 'handle' to 'Handle' it still is not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: have you checked what is actually 'returned' by get_product_pics? Have you checked what is actually in your database file?

Comment: *Facepalm* I am an idiot. You're right TheShiftExchange, when I moved my information from one database to another I screwed up something and the URLs were all NULL. I was looking at the wrong database the whole time. Thank you for the help both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entries in my database were NULL the whole time. Next time, check which database I am ACTUALLY working in.